# Why is drupal spitting out urls like entity:/node-1474 instead of /node-1474

Tags: 8, theming

So for the longest time I was using the following line of code to get urls instead of relying on drupals raw output. The main reason being I need an `<a>` tag to wrap several elements.

```
{{ item.content['#paragraph'].field_home_slider_button_link.0.value.uri }}
```

Inside of a field.

For a quick minute I contemplated just removing the `entity:`, however I'd really like to understand what's happening here and if there's a way to tell drupal I want the actual url in either twig or some setting?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `.url` instead of `.uri`, like this:

```
{{ item.content['#paragraph'].field_home_slider_button_link.0.url }}
```

I don’t think this works on older versions of Drupal 8, so if it doesn’t work you can try this:

```
{{ item.content['#paragraph'].field_home_slider_button_link.0['#url'] }}
```